# Dealing with timezone related error in the case of dynamic timezone in php

Tags: php

I have a scenario where I will be calculating date differences and each value could be from a different timezone which I fetch from a json string. Hence I cannot use default_date function.

However I'm getting the following error. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
```

My code:

```
$comp_timezone = $cron->get_company_time_zone($obj[$i]->company_id);
$cur_date = $cron->timezone_based_cur_date_time($comp_timezone);
$cur_timestamp = strtotime($cur_date);
$created_on_timestamp = strtotime($obj[$i]->created_on);
$date_diff = $cur_timestamp - $created_on_timestamp;
```

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning. It means PHP doesn't know which timezone you want to use by default, so it's using whatever your server is configured to use -- which can lead to unexpected results. You should specify a timezone in your `php.ini` file or call `date_default_timezone_set();` to explicitly set it for that script.

Comment: @rickdenhaan but as I have mentioned in the question I cannot set a default timezone for the script as I use dynamic timezones. Are you trying to say that I can set the default timezone and then in the same script use dynamic timezones?

Comment: Right now, PHP is already defaulting to whatever timezone is configured on your server. You can always try it out to see what happens ;-) Personally, if I'm dealing with timezones, I always use `DateTime` objects because they provide an easy way to explicitly set the timezone on each object.